# Infinite loop in elastic search scan response

Tags: python, elasticsearch, generator

I am doing a very simple scan search on ES using python client. For some reason, the result set is going into an infinite loop. Can some one help?

```
# import
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import scan

es = Elasticsearch()
es.indices.create(index="analytics", ignore=400)

query = { "query": { "match_all": {} } }

result = scan(client=es, query=query, index="keywords", doc_type="eyelytics", scroll="1m")

# It goes into infinite loop here
for r in result:
    print(r) 
    # print(result)
```

Comment: Is it really infinite? You're printing the entire result each time instead of r, which for a big result can take a while.

Comment: In the output I get an infinite stream of this:

    <generator object scan at 0x1043ad728>
    <generator object scan at 0x1043ad728>
    <generator object scan at 0x1043ad728>

Comment: why are printing result while trying to iterate over result?

Comment: I want to process the result set by adding some more key values in the doc. I added print just for debugging.

Comment: Ohh!! I got it!! Silly.

Comment: Can you update your question after you try `for r in result: print(r)`?

Comment: Done! So is this returning all the documents or do I need to call scan() again to get the next batch of results?